# Android Web browser homepage

Tags: android, browser, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider

I have seen several apps and advertising networks like startapp changing the android web browser homepage by code. How is this possible?

I have taken a look at the startapp sdk but i have not managed to find the part where they change the homepage.

I have also taken a look at the `BrowserSettings` in  `com.android.browser.BrowserSettings`

In `BrowserSettings`, there is a interface called `setHomepage(Context, String)`.

```
public void setHomePage(Context context, String url) {
    Editor ed = PreferenceManager.
            getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
    ed.putString(PREF_HOMEPAGE, url);
    ed.commit();
    homeUrl = url;
}
```

I dont know a lot java/android, so correct me if i am wrong: The `setHomepage()` is not declared static so it can not be called from other activities. So i can not use this.

I cant see any Mode applied to the Shared Preferences so it means that it will by default take Private as is Mode and i cant edit the Shared Preferences or ?

Some people have said that it may would be possible to do with contentProvider/Resolver.

Link for [BrowserSettings.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/android/browser/BrowserSettings.java#BrowserSettings.setHomePage%28android.content.Context%2Cjava.lang.String%29)

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated:)

Comment: Is it because you wan't to launch the browser on a certain page?

Comment: @AndersMetnik I dont really understand what you mean. I want to set the homepage of the browser by code. Not to launch a url.

Comment: You mean you want to set the default homepage ?

Comment: Yes, i want to be able to set the "default" homepage by code like the user can in the preference activity of the browser

Comment: Doubt you are able to change another programs settings, it would surely be a hack if you did.
If they have added such an option to some browsers it will be done by an intent

Comment: Do you have any example that I can download and check if they change the default home page? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @AkashKava Yes, have a look at this link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.wanddstudios.startapp

Comment: @Anonym..: The app you link to here does not change the home page of Browser or Chrome on a Nexus S running Android 4.1.

Comment: @CommonsWare hmm, I have tried it on htc aria 2.2 and Samsung S2 running 4.0.4. Both of these are non-rooted. The application manage to change the homepage. Be aware that there is a delay of the changin. It takes about 20-30 before the changing take place. Any idea on how this is done?

Comment: With luck, it has simply been blocked. Apps should not be able to attack other apps this way.

Comment: Yes, i totally agreed. If you have time to look at a file and see if you find the anwser i will give u 100 rep. Curious :) http://www.mediafire.com/?j4bqrguuqha4403

Answer (score 3):

I'm with [Diane HackBorn (Google's Android Engineer) on this one](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/HJNUzs5Fu7A/_0ghwZ7fnx0J): this shouldn't be possible, as it would be a platform security flaw.

If it happens to be possible, would be through some sort of hack (i.e.: an App with root access that can write into the Browser app Settings file directly).

Answer (score 1):

I see that you mentioned startapp. I have looked through their decompiled [SDK](http://www.mediafire.com/?j4bqrguuqha4403) but i cant find anything about the "changing homepage part".

Also i know that they do this but i cant find it in the SDK. Maybe somebody with better understanding for android can take a look at it. I have a android phone with 2.2 without root access and they managed to change the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

With root permissions, you can go to the /data/app/com.android.browser/shared_prefs

you have there the XML file for the shared preferences.

You just need to edit `PREF_HOMEPAGE` xml entry.

without root it is impossible, since you will need root permissions to access that directory.