# change browser home page in android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to change private shared preferences of android default browser using this code

```
Context browserContext = null;
    try {
        browserContext = createPackageContext("com.android.browser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    SharedPreferences sp = browserContext.getSharedPreferences("com.android.browser_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);                 
    SharedPreferences.Editor edidor = sp.edit();
    edidor.putString("homepage", "http://www.yahoo.com");
    edidor.commit();
```

Log cat is as follows

```
 08-26 12:44:20.106: W/ApplicationContext(6673): Attempt to read preferences file       /data/data/com.android.browser/shared_prefs/com.android.browser_preferences.xml without    permission
 08-26 12:44:20.116: E/ApplicationContext(6673): Couldn't rename file /data/data/com.android.browser/shared_prefs/com.android.browser_preferences.xml to backup file /data/data/com.android.browser/shared_prefs/com.android.browser_preferences.xml.bak
```

But this results in an access denied error.

How can I change the home page of a browser? Can it be done using NDK code?

Comment: Following link might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9679076/1554935

Comment: @sur007 yes its duplicate because its does not solve my problem

Comment: can i do it with native code , i have no idea about ndk

Comment: look onto this 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035410/how-to-access-the-android-browser-settings-via-code 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649516/how-to-open-default-browser-settings-from-my-android-application?lq=1

Comment: It's not possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352452/android-web-browser-homepage 2. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1362479